# Counting number of yields by an iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

One can consider the functions

```
def f(iterator):
    count = 0
    for _ in iterator:
        count += 1
    return count

def g(iterator):
    return len(tuple(iterator))
```

I *believe* the only way they can differ is that `g` might run out of memory while `f` doesn't.

Assuming I'm right about that:

> Is there a faster and/or otherwise-better (roughly, shorter without becoming code-golf)
>   way to get `f(iterator)` while using less memory than `tuple(iterator)` takes up,
>   preferably inline rather than as a function?

(If there is some other way for  `f`, `g` ​to differ, then I believe that
`f` is more likely than `g` to properly define the functionality I'm after.
I already looked at [the itertools documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html), and don't see any solution there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sum` with generator expression yielding 1 for every item in iterator:

```
>>> it = (i for i in range(4))
>>> sum(1 for _ in it)
4
```